# Compare the second column in file 1 and the second column in file 2 in linux

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have two files, file 1 and file 2. I want to suppose when the chromosome number are the same, if the second column in file 1 is greater than (the second column - 1,000) in file 2 and smaller than (the second column + 1,000) in file 2, then output the fourth column in file 2 and the third column in file 1.

File 1 (3 columns):

```
chr1 12000 1  
chr2 12700 2  
chr2 13000 0.5
```

File 2 (4 columns):

```
chr1 11869 14409 gene_id=ENSG00000223972  
chr1 11869 14409 gene_id=ENSG00000224000  
chr2 11869 12227 gene_id=ENSG00000300000  
chr2 12613 12721 gene_id=ENSG00000270000  
chr2 13221 14409 gene_id=ENSG00000400000
```

Output (2 columns):

```
gene_id=ENSG00000223972  1  
gene_id=ENSG00000270000  2  
gene_id=ENSG00000400000  0.5
```

I tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{if ((a[$2]>$2-1000) && (a[$2]<$2+1000)){print $4, a[$3]}}' file1 file2
```

But I got nothing.

How can I get the desired output in linux quickly?

Comment: you don't save column#2 from file1, so with conditions likr `a[$2]>$2-1000` containing `a[$2]` you cannot get file1's second column's value for comparison against file2 same second column. additionally in the output you need 3rd column if the file1, but that one is also nowhere you save them

Comment: Can you tell me how to save column#2 from file 1 using awk or how to write the script for my purpose, please? I have no much experience in "awk". Thank you very much. It confuses me for a long time.

Comment: If this is really a bioinformatics question It would be great if you could provide names for the individual columns, thx.

Comment: unfortunately your question is completely unclear; what is the "key-mapping" between these two files? if it's col1 then how do you handle the first&second lines of the file1 for the "char2" and comparing which one against which lines in file2? please [edit] your question